# Matrix api different distance to same coordinates

Tags: rest, here-api

I've been trying using the here api to calculate matrixes many-to-many, so that i can later solve a TSP.

Problem is that if I start from one city, and get the distance to the same city, it thinks that from the same city to the same city there is a distance of 2 (meters?).

Also, if I check the distance between point A and point B and then Point B and point A, there's a slight difference.

Is this normal or is it a bug in the API?

the REST url is the following:

https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?start0=45.69523%2C9.66951&start1=45.85167%2C9.39188&destination0=45.69523%2C9.66951&destination1=45.85167%2C9.39188&summaryAttributes=distance&mode=fastest%3Bcar&app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}

Answer (score 0):

The routing service is based on link segment. That explains the 2meters between the same city center.
Concerning your second topic: I had a look at the locations of A and B. They are both surrounded by one way streets. You need to consider that it is sometimes not possible to route the exact route back than before and then the distances might be different.

Comment: What do you mean by "The routing service is based on link segment."? Does that explain a non-zero distance and time for routes between the same lat/lon co-ords?